# Why the same configured servers return different encoding of responce of xslt transformation?

Tags: java, excel, xml, xslt, websphere

i try to transform xml to xls. It done and work well on `DEV` enviroment, all tests passed. But when i deploy my app on `TEST` enviroment it doesn't work.
The problem in file encoding. After xslt transformation on `DEV` server xml that discribe excel workheets returns in `utf-8`. But on `TEST` server it returs with `win-1251`. Same configured websphere on win server 2008 R2 enterprise. What could go wrong?

here is part of my xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" byte-order-mark="yes" version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
    <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
    </xsl:text>
            <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:s....
```

i was trying with BOM without BOM, it doesn't help.

Comment: Best to put that information in the question.

Comment: Do you write Java code to perform the XSLT transformation? If so, show the relevant Java code.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem I guess, but in XSLT, to create a processing instruction like `<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>` in the transformation result, use https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-processing-instruction e.g. `<xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>`.